# How to disable Tooltipster using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tooltipster

some of plugins in wordpress use tooltip, and i tried to disable it using jquery but couldn't do so.
my html is

```
<div class="tooltipster-base tooltip-theme tooltipster-fade tooltipster-fade-show" 
style="transition-duration: 350ms; animation-duration: 350ms; top: 1596px; left: 45px;">
```

if i disable it using css {display:none} it will be hidden but the functionality will still exist in background,

i tried to use this code

```
$ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".tooltipster-base.tooltip-theme.tooltipster-fade.tooltipster-fade-show").prop("disabled", true); 
});
```

but didn't work

thanks for any help :)

Comment: You can remove the tooltip classes with .removeClass("tooltipster-base tooltip-theme tooltipster-fade tooltipster-fade-show")